# Laravel Eloquent how to query the avrege and compare it between two values

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am looking for a solution to filte jobs basing on the salary.
I have a `Job` model which has 2 column `min_salary` and `max_salary`, and the user is going to use a slider to pick two values as min and max salary.
I have tried the `whereBetween` and `orWhereBetween` but the problem is the query gets closed and I can't proceed with other filters, so am trying to get the average between the model min/max salary and use it instead of the two slaries.

Here's what i tried:

```
  $salary = explode(',',$request->salary); // geting the salary range from the request as array
  $jobs  = Job::whereBetween('min_salary',$salary)->orWhereBetween('max_salary',$salary);
```

This solution does not work as I want, as I can't proceed with other filters.
I also tried to do a custom `orWhere` function and do seperated `whereBetween` queries, but I got the same result.

What I am trying now is to get the average between the model max and min salary without creating another field*, and then proceed to do something like that :

```
  $jobs  = Job::whereBetween('theCalculatedAvg',$salary);
```

I appreciate any help with any kind of solution that does not require creating another field in the database, and i wont mind an sql raw solution if it does the job.

Thank you.

Update

Heres the whole function u had :

```
 if($request->has('offset')) {

        $salary = explode(',',$request->salary);
        $jobs  = Job::whereBetween('min_salary',$salary)->orWhereBetween('max_salary',$salary);
        if ($request->has('lat')) {
            $sqlDistance = DB::raw
            ('
          ( 6371 * acos
              ( cos
                  ( radians
                      (' . $request->lat . ')
                  )
              * cos
                  ( radians
                      ( lat )
                  )
              * cos
                  ( radians
                      ( lon )
                  - radians
                      (' . $request->lon . ')
                  )
              + sin
                  ( radians
                      (' . $request->lat  . ')
                  )
              * sin
                  ( radians
                      ( lat )
                  )
              )
          )
        ');
            $jobs->when($sqlDistance != null, function ($query) use ($sqlDistance,$request){
                $query->whereHas('address', function ($subQuery) use ($sqlDistance,$request) {
                    $subQuery->addSelect(DB::raw("{$sqlDistance} AS distance"));
                    $subQuery->havingRaw("distance <= ?", [(int)$request->range]);
                });
            })
                ->with('company')
                ->with('address');


        }

        if ($request->has('key')) {
            $jobs->where('title', 'like', '%' . $request->key . '%');
        }

        if ($request->has('cat')) {
            $cat = explode(',',$request->cat);

            $jobs->whereIn('category_id', $cat);
        }

        if ($request->has('type')) {
            $type = explode(',',$request->type);

            $jobs->whereIn('type', $type);
        }

        if($request->has('hs')) {

            return view("General::browseJobs", [
                'jobs' => $jobs->orderBy('created_at','desc')->skip($request->offset * 2)->take(2)->get(),
                'count' => count($jobs->get())
            ]);

        }

        $view = view('General::loaders.jobs', [
            'jobs' => $jobs->orderBy('created_at','desc')->skip($request->offset * 2)->take(2)->get()
        ])->render();

        return response()->json(['html' => $view , 'count' => count($jobs->get()) ]);

    }



    return view("General::browseJobs", [
        'jobs' => Job::orderBy('created_at','desc')->take(2)->get(),
        'count' => count(Job::all())
    ]);
```

The issue is that i just want the salary filter to work this way:
lets say the user picked twho values : $min and $max (will be stored in an array)

now i want to show him the jobs where the min_salary is between [$min, $max]
or the max_salary is between [$min, $max].

NB : if i use :

```
Job::whereBetween('min_salary',$salary)->whereBetween('max_salary',$salary);
```

without the or it works just fine, but i want the or logic to be implemented.

Comment: I think what you need to do is query on a subquery. The exact query cannot be assembled from our perspective as you did not provide enough info. If you can provide us with the table layout and an example of the data you would like to select, I'm willing to give it a go :)

Comment: Hello Rob, actually i have tried a subquery the issue is that when i use the orWhereBetwwen it gets reset all the other filters and return a collection filtered just by the salary.

Comment: If you terminate the query and resume using a collection, you are not doing subqueries right ;) Can you provide table info and requested result? I will elaborate ;)

Comment: Here's the subquery i tries (and i tried others) : 

      ` $jobs  = Job::whereBetween('min_salary',$salary)->orWhere(function 
        ($query) use ($salary){
         $query->whereBetween('max_salary' , $salary);
         }); `

Comment: Ok, so say you get 2 salary values from user. Lets call them $min and $max. Can you not query: `Job::where('min_salary', '>=', $min)->where('max_salary', '<=', $max);`?

Comment: Hi Rob, thanks for keeping with me, actually thats not what i need, i want the filter to work the way it shows him the jobs where the max or the min are included in the range he picked.

Comment: Do you have a working raw-sql version of what you want? Because the way the question is formulated I could keep going for couple of hours suggesting things :P

Comment: What Kind of filters do you want to add? Do the filters work only in AND conditions, or also in grouped OR conditions? How do you want the average salary to be calculated?

Comment: I will update the question with the whole code, and i will explain further what i really want.

Comment: Thank you, I will read your question when ready :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to scope the `or` to those 2 conditions only:

```php
Jobs::where(function ($q) use ($salary) {
  $q->whereBetween('min_salary',$salary)->orWhereBetween('max_salary',$salary);
})
```

To understand why this is required, you need to consider the sql query produced by eloquent.

If you write:

```
$jobs = Jobs::where([condition1])->orWhere([condition2]);
.. some other code..
$jobs->where([condition3]);
...
$jobs->where([condition4]);
```

The resulting query will be:

```
SELECT *
FROM jobs
WHERE [condition1] OR [condition2] AND [condition3] AND [condition4]
```

But in SQL, the AND operator has precedence over the OR, so the conditions are logically considered like this:

```
([condition1]) OR ([condition2] AND [condition3] AND [condition4])
```

This is not the behavior you want.

By scoping the OR condition  in  a where closure, you basically tell eloquent to add a parenthesis around the conditions, so:

```
$jobs = Jobs::where(function ($q) {
 $q->where([condition1])->orWhere([condition2]);
});
.. some other code..
$jobs->where([condition3]);
...
$jobs->where([condition4]);
```

Results in the following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM jobs
WHERE ([condition1] OR [condition2]) AND [condition3] AND [condition4]
```

which is the desidered one

Comment: Hello gbalduzzi, thank you so much, can you please explain the solution further am really curious!

Comment: I edited my answer to explain the solution, I hope it is not too confused

Comment: Thank you so much, it makes so much sense now.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, thank you for updating the question. I'm pretty sure I'm not able to answer it in one go, but I'll do my best.

As far as I can see, you are working on a Job site where you want to allow users to enter filters, and only show jobs matching those filters.

I see you have filters for min/max salary, distance, title, categories and types.

You also have a `hs` key which decides which view to open with which data.

I would consider the min/max salary to be an OR statament, and the rest an AND.

In that case I would do

```
$mainQuery = Job::where(function($query) use($salary)
{ 
    $query->whereBetween('min_salary', $salary)->orWhereBetween('max_salary', $salary);
});
```

So you can do `$mainQuery->where('anothermust-have', $somevalue)`;

Comment: Hey Rob, thank you so much, actually yes thats the key, but i still can't figure out why should i scope it in a where query, i will appreciate it if you can explain the logic behind it. (the hs key goes for home search if u'r curious xD) .

Comment: Sure, it is the way filtering works. Check truth tables https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_table for instance. If you would have written the query in pure SQL you would have noticed you needed to do roughly the same in the `where` statement, where you have to group the `AND` and `OR` with `(` and `)`. Main reason is the order in which statements are resolved in sql itself. Even better, If you run `DB::enableQueryLog()` before running(using `get()`)  the query, and `dd(DB::getQueryLog())` after you run the query, you can see the query(ies) that are runned, with bound params.